# How to get children of ObjectName using JMX API

Tags: java, wildfly

I need to get all children objects of a resource available in the application server (the list of available datasources).
I'm using this piece of code for this  purpose:

```
ObjectName name = new ObjectName("jboss.as:subsystem=datasources");
Set<ObjectInstance> instances = server.queryMBeans(name, null);

Iterator<ObjectInstance> iterator = instances.iterator();

while (iterator.hasNext()) {
    ObjectInstance instance = iterator.next();

    System.out.println("MBean Found:");
    System.out.println("Class Name:" + instance.getClassName());
    System.out.println("Object Name:" + instance.getObjectName());
}
```

However, I'm only able to retrieve the object name for "jboss.as:subsystem=datasources" but I need to find the available datasources, which are under that tree. I cannot find any method in the ObjectInstance to dig into it.
Any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can query the MBeans tree and filter through the Objects by name:

```
Set<ObjectInstance> instances = connection.queryMBeans(null, null);
Iterator<ObjectInstance> iterator = instances.iterator();

while (iterator.hasNext()) {
    ObjectInstance instance = iterator.next();
    if (instance.getObjectName().toString().startsWith("jboss.as:subsystem=datasources,data-source=") &&
            (!instance.getObjectName().toString().contains(",statistics")))
    System.out.println("Object Name:" + instance.getObjectName());

}
```

Make sure, if using the remote+http protocol to include the jboss-client JAR in your classpath.
More details: [How do I know the list of Datasources in JBoss](http://www.mastertheboss.com/jboss-server/jboss-datasource/how-do-i-get-the-list-of-datasources-available)